# List order in android devices different

Tags: android, collections, android-listview, android-sqlite, device

I'm having a hard time to understand why the list order of an `arrayList` is the opposite in different android devices. For example in Asus Nexus 7 the List (of some items that i want to show in a `ListView` )  is well ordered however in Galaxy Tab 2 the order is the opposite.
When I call `Collections.reverse(items);` 
the order become good in Galaxy while wrong in the Nexus !!!!
this is coming from the SQLite database that place items in different orders in every device !!! Why is that ? is that normal

Comment: Does your SQL statement have an `ORDER BY` clause ? Without it there is no guarantee that the results will be returned in any order.

Comment: the thing is I'm using GreenDAO to manipulate the database so I only call `doaSession.loadAll();` I populate the database the same in all devices I parse an XML file and get the items and save them in the database...

Comment: ok. But do you use the `ORDER BY` clause on your query ?

Comment: I tried to look at the GreenDao code source to figure out is using " Order By" clause, I found that it's not used ! 
but what could change if it's not used! I don't understand why when I insert rows in some order in the database that order would be reversed in some devices !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that SQL will return results in the same order as the order in which the rows were inserted. This is not part of the spec. If you need to guarantee that results are ordered, use the `ORDER BY` clause on a particular column.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak, I thought I would have the same order that when inserted but you may be right I should use a column for order to guarantee the same order provided by the xml...